# Method chanining and re-use of same class

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

I have the following class:

```
class DB {

    private $name;

    public function load($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

At the moment if I do:

```
$db = new DB();
echo $db->load('foo')->get() . "<br>";
echo $db->load('fum')->get() . "<br>";
```

This outputs "foo" then "fum".

However if I do this:

```
$db = new DB(); 
$foo = $db->load('foo');
$fum = $db->load('fum');
echo $foo->get() . "<br>";
echo $fum->get() . "<br>";
```

It always outputs "fum".

I can sort of see why it would do that, but how could I keep the variable seperate to each instance without having to create a new instance of DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you mean for DB to be some sort of database connectivity object (which I assume you are), multiple instances may not be the best choice.  Perhaps something like this may be what you are trying to do:

```
$db = new DB(); 
$foo = $db->load('foo')->get();
$fum = $db->load('fum')->get();
echo $foo . "<br>";
echo $fum . "<br>";
```

If what I think you are trying to do is correct, it may be better to separate your get logic from the DB class into its own Record class.

```
class Record {
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function get(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    private $name;
}

class DB {

    public function load($name) {
        return new Record($name);
    }
}

$db = new DB(); 
$foo = $db->load('foo');
$fum = $db->load('fum');
echo $foo->get() . "<br>";
echo $fum->get() . "<br>";
```

Comment: If you read my code I have already done that, I am trying to re-use the class without having to initiate it again each time whilst keeping the variables seperate.

Comment: This is slightly different than what you have above, it keeps the variables separate without initializing the class again.

Comment: Yes but if I wanted to use $foo and call another function further down the code I would have to run $db->load again!

Answer (score 2):

To keep it separate to each instance, you would, by definition, need to create a new instance... You could do that though in the `load()` method. Instead of returning `$this`, you could return a `new DB()` configured the way you want. Then make the method static.

This is what's called [the factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: @fire that's not what I mean... The factory method should not return a singleton, but rather a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing in your code is similar to PHP's pass by reference feature.

When you set the first variable, `$foo` is equal to the value of `$db->name`, when you call it again to set it to 'fum', you're setting `$fum` equal to `$db->name`. Since you're echoing them both at the end, they're both going to be the last value you set it to.

Try this and see if your results are different.

```
$db = new DB(); 

$foo = $db->load('foo');
echo $foo->get() . "<br>";

$fum = $db->load('fum');
echo $fum->get() . "<br>";
```

When you run `$db->load()`, create a new object and return that instead of the object you're currently in.

Comment: What does this have to do with pass-by-reference? From what I see: nothing. He's just manipulating the same instance thorough the code (he's never passing it anywhere). The rest of your answer is right though.

Comment: left out the words 'similar to'